# Using JAXB inside a Confluence Plugin

Tags: plugins, jaxb, confluence, springsource-dm-server

I have a Confluence plugin I am working on that contains a series of classes that use JAXB.  When the plugin runs I get the following runtime-exception:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  - with linked exception:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:152)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:299)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:244)
```

My pom.xml file has the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
        <artifactId>confluence</artifactId>
        <version>${confluence.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>func-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.3-beta1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jwebunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jwebunit-htmlunit-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the dependency to JAXB in your pom.xml.

This may already be provided by Confluence.